# Disable System Beeps over SSH

Tags: linux, bash, audio

I have disabled system beeps locally by adding `set bell-style none` to my local `.inputrc` file; however, when remote ssh to machines I will still get system beeps for using TAB for autocomplete, which I do a lot. I know I can modify the remote machine's `.inputrc` file or the remote accounts `.bashrc` file, but that is intrusive on machines I do not own. Is there a way to fix this locally.

I am using Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash.

The beeps are slowing driving me insane.

Comment: What SSH client do you use?

Comment: OpenSSH, to be more specific `OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Comment: You should look for a configuration option in your Windows terminal emulator to convert bell to a visible bell, like `xterm -vb` does in Unix.

Comment: I do wonder why you consider it "intrusive" to create personal configuration files on a remote system. I mean, assuming you have an account and a home directory of your own, as usual, that's the usual way to do it. Things get a lot easier if you have a set of configuration files you can copy to any remote system to handle stuff like this.

Comment: It's only intrusive if you are sharing the remote account with others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a workaround, first, create a file `.inputrc.mine` in the home directory of your remote user with line

```
set bell-style none
```

then log in to the server using

```
ssh -t user@server 'export INPUTRC=~/.inputrc.mine; /bin/bash'
```

Without `-t` your bash would not work (input/output redirected to the previous command).

Comment: Are you sure that works? Try running `set bell-style none; echo "$1";` on an interactive Bash and see what happens.

Comment: No, it doesn't, you are right.

Comment: I've added a working solution.

Comment: `ssh -t user@server 'INPUTRC=~/.inputrc.mine /bin/bash'` should work as well.

Comment: You are riight.

Comment: I think this is the best solution given that there does not appear to be a way to tell SSH or the local Bash application to ignore system beeps.

Answer (score 9):

You can set readline variables at any time using the `bind` command, without needing to read an `.inputrc` file. For example, after you login type

```
bind 'set bell-style none'
```

Note how the command has to be a single string.  If you want to do this automatically each time you could use a simple `expect` script taking the remote hostname as argument.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh [lindex $argv 0]
expect {$ }
send "bind 'set bell-style none'\n"
expect {$ }
interact
```